# webdriver.io rightClick immediately closes when executing tests, but works in repl

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

We're writing tests in webdriver.io 4.14.0 (with mocha and chai) , and I'm running into a strange issue that I can't get to the bottom of.

The issue revolves around the following code:

```
var elem = $("#myid");
elem.waitForText();
elem.rightClick() // also tried browser.rightClick("#myid");
```

In both cases above, the expectation is that a context menu in our application appears.  When running the test from the console, I can see the context menu flash briefly, and disappear (this causes other commands to then fail since the required elements aren't visible).

The weird thing (to me) is that if I put browser.debug(), enter repl mode and execute the same commands there, everything works, and the context menu stays open.

Is there something that I'm missing when writing the test case?

I've tried both the stable 3.* and 4.0 alpha packages of selenium. Additionally, I'm using Chrome 71.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else encounters something like this, make sure you find something on your page that you can use to determine if any scripts are running. In my case, other scripts were trying to overwrite the DOM and closing the menu (something that wasn't happening in REPL because they had already finished).